# Consuming WCF service in Console Application

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net, console-application

I am New to this site. I am currently working on wcf . I am trying to achieve somethig from this hard work but i am facing some problems.I have WCF service running in my MS Visual Stuido 2015 which have local class named AccountBalance and this class got several string propertys like account_number, account_balace etc .I created database in MS Sql server. Currently i am consuming wcf service in a console Application .I am trying to retrive the record from database in console window by using account number as key. when i enter the account number it should display the rest of record from database in console application but i getting error saying that and i can not run it . 
**cannot convert from 'string' to MyService.AccountBalanceRequest'**
Here is class code which inherits from another base class..

```
           [DataContract]
         public class AccountBalanceRequest : Current_Account_Details
            {
    string account_number;

    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Number
    {
        get { return account_number; }
        set { account_number = value; }
    }
}
```

}

Here is ADO.NET CODE..

```
      public bool AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 
             Current_Account_Details WHERE Account_Number ='" + 
              accountNumber.Account_Number + "'", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", 
                accountNumber.Account_Number);
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;

            }

        }
    }
```

Here is Console Application Code..

```
      public static void Balance()
    {
        MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient currentAccount = new MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IHalifaxCurrentAccou
            ntService");

        MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs = new MyService.AccountBalanceRequest();


        string AccountNumber;


        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your Account Number--------:");
        AccountNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        cs.Account_Number = AccountNumber;
         MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs1 = 

     currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(AccountNumber);//Error on this line.

                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Number is :" + cs.Account_Number);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Type :" + cs.Account_Balance);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Account Fee :" + cs.Account_Fee);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Balance:" + cs.Account_Balance);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Over Draft Limit :" + cs.Over_Draft_Limit);

                Console.Write("--------------------------");
                Console.ReadLine();




    }
```

i also tried this way as well. the code did rise any error but did not give expected result. here is the code.

```
  public static void Balance()
    {
        MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient currentAccount = new MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IHalifaxCurrentAccountService");
        MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs = new MyService.AccountBalanceRequest();


        string AccountNumber;


        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your Account Number--------:");
        AccountNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        cs.Account_Number = AccountNumber;
        // MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs1 = currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(AccountNumber);



       if (currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs))
        {

                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Number is :" + cs.Account_Number);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Type :" + cs.Account_Balance);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Account Fee :" + cs.Account_Fee);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Balance:" + cs.Account_Balance);
                Console.WriteLine("Your Account Over Draft Limit :" + cs.Over_Draft_Limit);

                Console.Write("--------------------------");
                Console.ReadLine();
                //Console.Clear();


       }

    }
```

Here is the image for out put.[This is image of the out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv2xx.png)

Comment: Any suggestions or solutions??

Comment: Hint: Where are you populating the values read from the database to your object ? You are using `@Account_Number`, BUT your SQL statement does NOT use it.

Comment: Ok. In ado.net and console application

Comment: You would need to populate your object with the values from the DB and return it. Take a look at the first example here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

you can also change your method signature as follows: `public AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(string accountNumber)` - i.e., input parameter is the string, the return value is your object. You have to read from the DB (via DatabaseReader) and populate your object

Comment: The link you provided this not actually interact with WCF service. Thanks @Subbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right way is:

```
currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs);
```

Not:

```
currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(AccountNumber);
```

Because the type of parameter is `MyService.AccountBalanceRequest`, not `string`.

I hope to be helpful for you :)

Comment: i did try but when i enter the account number in console window its only pint account number but not rest database record. Thanks Ali